# C++ binary search tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Recently I have started playing around with C++, namely classes and pointers. I looked around for similar questions, but nothing helped.

I have a binary search tree class that holds some information in string format (well, char *), but after adding a new node to the tree, I cannot get the information back, as it returns junk.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
class Node
{
    Node *lNode;
    Node *rNode;
    char *name;
    public:
        void setName(char *n) { name = n; }
        char *getName() { return name; }
}

class Tree
{
    Node *root;
    Node *addNode(Node *, Node *);
    public:
        Tree() { root = NULL };
        int addNewNode(Node *);
        void print();
};

int Tree::addNewNode(Node *n)
{
    root = addNode(root, n);
    cout << root->getName() << endl;   // this returns the name correctly
}

Node *Tree::addNode(Node *subtree, Node *node)
{
    if(subtree== NULL)
    {
        subtree = node;
    }
    else if(node->getName() <= subtree->getLeft())
    {
        subtree->setLeft(addNode(subtree->getLeft(), node));
    }
    else
    {
        subtree->setRight(addNode(subtree->getRight(), node));
    }

    return subtree;
}

void Tree::print()
{
    cout << root->getName() << endl;    // this does not!
}
```

And this is where I call the methods:

```
Tree *myTree = new Tree();

Node *n = new Node();
n->setName(name);
myTree->addNewNode(n);
```

The tree variable is a private member attribute of an outer container class, and actually gets created outside that class to be passed into the constructor. When I invoke the addNewNode method, that adds a Node to the tree, but when I want to print out the name of the node stored in the root, it just comes up with junk. I guess there's a haywire pointer somewhere, but I cannot find it for the life of me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::map` or `std::set` ?

Comment: Don't name your parameter with the same name as your member. You're going to make a mistake doing it that way...

Comment: That was stupid of me. Changed it to 'subtree', but still the same.

Comment: What is the 'city' element?

Comment: `if(subtree == NULL) { root = city; }`: what's `city`?

Comment: That's supposed to be node. I tidied up the names, seems like a left that there. Sorry.

Comment: @straphe: Please post your *real* code

Comment: You also need to initialize your `lNode` and `rNode` pointers to `NULL` in `Node`'s constructor. Otherwise they are uninitialized data.

Comment: @Dark Falcon, still the same.

Comment: `if(node->getName() <= subtree->getLeft())` is comparing a `Node*` with a `char*`. Is this a typo as well?

Comment: @Andy, hahh, changed that to subtree->getLeft()->getName(). Still the same.

Comment: @straphe: `subtree->getLeft()` may return `NULL` though

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch to answer your question in the first comment, because using std::map<> or std::set<> accomplishes nothing to assist in the openly-admitted learning curve approach stated in the very first sentence of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll guess that you're passing in a string pointer name to `setName` and just copying the pointer to `name` (as opposed to reallocating and saving the string).  Later, the original object is gone, and your object `name` is left pointing to garbage.  Trying using std::string for `name` instead, or create your own memory with `name = new char[ strlen(n) + 1 ]` and strcpy/memcpy it in.  And don't forget to `delete [] name` at object destruction if you go that route.

Comment: And that fixed it. Thank you very much. I still need to wrap my head around the scope of some variables. Thanks very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

When root is null, you set it to city rather than node.  There's your problem.